# Web API Requests happening enormous times

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am calling WEB API call using the following code in web service(.asmx).

```
        Server.ScriptTimeout = 3600; 
        return util.util.Settle(ids, userName, userPwd, userBelongCountry);
```

Settle method invokes MakeRequest() as given below:

```
   public Dictionary<string, string> MakeRequest(string addressAPI)
    {
        HttpWebRequest r=null;
        try
        {
            r = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(addressAPI);
            r.Method = "Get";
            HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)r.GetResponse();
            Stream sr = res.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader sre = new StreamReader(sr);
            var s = sre.ReadToEnd();
            sre.Close();
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(s);
            foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants().Where(p => p.HasElements == false))
            {
                int keyInt = 0;
                string keyName = element.Name.LocalName;

                while (!this.dataDictionary.ContainsKey(keyName))
                {
                    keyName = element.Name.LocalName + "_" + keyInt++;
                    this.dataDictionary.Add(keyName, element.Value);
                }
            }

            return this.dataDictionary;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SystemLogWebCom.Error("Error in WEBAPI call" + ex.ToString());            
            return null;
            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

Problem:If any exception occurred the WEB API is getting called enormous times approx.15000+ times continuously. It supposed to execute once and return back.

Error logged in Logger:
"Error in WEBAPI callSystem.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add) at WebAPICommunicator.Utility.MakeRequest(String addressAPI)".

I am wondering how come these many number of times it is invoking and the same number of errors i could see in Logger.

Now I have included

finally
            {

```
            r.Abort();

        }
```

Can it solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

First is that you don't dispose streams in a finally block. 
And second that your exception will never be re thrown because nothing will be executed after "return null" in catch, "throw ex;" is dead code.
Your exception is been thrown because of you using while instead of if:

```
while (!this.dataDictionary.ContainsKey(keyName))

if (!this.dataDictionary.ContainsKey(keyName))
```

Dictionaries can not contain duplicate keys, and that's what is happening here the second time you read the same key from xml.

Comment: Yes,you are correct Dictionary cant not contain duplicate values. But after invoking API it always returns unique set of key and value in dictionary. I suspect here multiple times API Getting called simultaneously trying to add key and value pair. I am wondering what would be the reason of invoking API many number of times?

Comment: Without more code is impossible to tell. Place breakpoints in the relevant places to see what's going on under the hood.